# Is it possible to make an extra page from scratch in Blogger?

Tags: html, blogger

I want to add pages to a blog (in Blogger - https://www.blogger.com/home), but I want a different format and style for each of the pages on the blog.

I tried going to **[Blog Name] -> Pages -> New page** but the pages that are made uses the template of the main page, including the sidebar and header.  Honesty, it looked no different from a blog post.

Can I create a completely blank page and add in all the HTML myself?  Or is this not possible with Blogger?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but does require you to go into the editor and do some work.
Blogger uses xml, so you can write conditional tags. So above all of your content you could put the conditional tag, write up all of your HTML and then wrap the whole blog within the else statement.

Within the specific markup you'll need to include the whole tags for the content, like:

```
<!-- page title -->
<h1><a class='post-link' expr:href='data:i.link'><data:i.title/></a></h1>

<!-- page content -->
<data:i.body/>
```

otherwise you won't see whatever content you added within the page editor.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;p/yourpageurl.html&quot;'>
<!-- specific site markup -->
<b:else/>
<!-- All of the normal markup -->
</b:if>
```